# React router will mount component after push to anot

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Let's say I have two components. Component A and component B and I use react-router to navigate between them.

When in component A, I want to, (when i have no location from the react-router) push to component B. And i do it in the beginning of my constructor.

The question is, if i have code on my constructor or on my `componentDidMount` method, the code is executed anyways (despite successful push).

So what I really wanted would be to call the component right away so that, if i push to another route, no more code is executed.

Thank you.

Comment: I would say best thing would be to check the condition and load the exact component you want via use of Routes as the situation here suggests that you will already have your condition to load component B even before Component A is initialised. You should use that condition and render B rather than going to A and then moving to B.

Comment: I can't see how i would do that.

I have the following Routes component

```
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
        <Route exact path="/proxy-requests-page" component={ProxyRequestsPage} />
   
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: try using conditional `Redirect ` from react router 4.

Comment: The problem is that you do not have access to location prop if the component is not encapsulated with the withRouter HOC. Therefore i cannot make my condition :(

Comment: is your component not part of `Route` declaration ? if not then yes it will need withRouter HOC.